# Integration of SeleniumBase and Appium to leverage SeleniumBase API with mobile

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android, python-appium, seleniumbase

I'm currently working on a testing project where I need to perform both web and mobile testing. For web automation, I've been using SeleniumBase, which has proven to be quite helpful. For mobile automation, I'm using Appium. My goal is to integrate these two tools to utilize the functionality provided by SeleniumBase for mobile.

Would like to know is it possible to use SeleniumBase rich api for mobile ?
I did start appium server and created driver in Pytest fixtures

```
import pytest
import logging
from . import appium_server
from . import appium_driver

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)  # Set the desired logging level


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def run_appium_server():
    logging.getLogger("run_appium_server").debug("invoked appium server fixture")
    appium_server_instance = appium_server.start_appium_server()
    print(appium_server_instance)

    yield
    print("stopping appium server")
    appium_server.stop_appium_server(appium_server_instance)

    # driver.quit()


@pytest.fixture
def run_appium_driver(request, run_appium_server):

    print("function level appium driver")
    driver = appium_driver.start_appium_driver()
    print("Driver information:")
    print(driver)
    yield driver
    print("trying to quit driver, but commented")
    driver.quit()
```

My Test case file inherits BaseTestCase which inherits BaseCase class

```
class TestDemo(BaseTestCase):

    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("run_appium_driver")  # Use the fixture to get the driver
    def test_hello_world(self):
        print("executing test helllo world")
        print(run_appium_driver)
        
  self.base_test_case.find_element(By.ID,"com.company:id/get_started_button")


# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     TestDemo.main()

BaseTestCase.main(__name__, __file__)
```

This code is not working as selenium could not identify elements in mobile app.
Purpose of integration is to use the SeleniumBase api with appium to favor SeleniumBase api, reporting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to handle this. There's the built-in [SeleniumBase Mobile Mode](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/mobile_testing.md), which is activated with `--mobile` as a `pytest` command-line option. You can also customize that via other args:

```bash
--agent=STRING  (Modify the web browser User-Agent string.)
--mobile  (Use the mobile device emulator while running tests.)
--metrics=STRING  (Set mobile metrics: "CSSWidth,CSSHeight,PixelRatio".)
```

But if you need to use Appium with it, then see [SeleniumBase Syntax Format 9 - Overriding the driver via BaseCase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/syntax_formats.md#-9-overriding-the-driver-via-basecase), or see [SeleniumBase Syntax Format 10 - Overriding the driver via "sb" fixture](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/syntax_formats.md#-10-overriding-the-driver-via-sb-fixture).

You would basically rewrite `get_new_driver()` so that when SeleniumBase starts, it launches the Appium driver instead of the regular one for the test. If you're using pytest fixtures, you'll probably need format 10.

Assuming the regular Webdriver API is compatible with the Appium API, you'll be able to use the same methods with Appium that you can already use with Webdriver.

Comment: HI Michael , thanks for you response and inputs. I will check and work on that. 
Also, SeleniumBase BaseCase class , has imports from selenium web driver specifically. Does that mean BaseCase is specific to only web(like SeleniumBase team developed it, platform-dependent).

Comment: Hi @Vipul, SeleniumBase is for testing the web, but even mobile devices have a web interface for web pages, so there's common ground. SB mobile mode can accurately display the mobile versions of websites.

Comment: Added an article for teams who wanted to do integration SeleniumBase and Appium. @Michael Mintz
https://medium.com/@bvipul.k/creating-an-engaging-and-powerful-seleniumbase-and-appium-integration-df1dac05a7ef